# Strange `div` and `size` problem in Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have made [a badly designed page](http://vkis.co.in) using tables but everything on the page is working fine except when i click on `Advertiser Index` the page gets bad in `Internet Explorer 6`.

I cannot find anything in the page that may have caused the problem.

I have used the `css`

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

which i think either way is not interpreted by `IE`.

but the `div #body_text` does not increase width but the parent `td` increases its width.

Comment: the advertiser index link dosen't work in firefox in any page except the homepage.

Comment: @thomas i could not replicate your said prob... thanks for your time...

Comment: i m reposting as ie 8 also has this prob... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423064/strange-table-and-size-problem-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are targeting at a very specific customer group (for example an intranet application, where all are still using IE6) you really shouldn't waste your time with adopting your site to IE6. This browser is officially dead.

Comment: sure but people who do not use much computers they seldom do go for using any browser and they have ie...

Comment: i m reposting this question as ie 8 also has this problem.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423064/strange-table-and-size-problem-in-internet-explorer